# Prove that on a compact manifold, Laplacian can not take constant value

Tags: differential-geometry, laplacian

Prove that there is no function $\phi$ on a compact manifold without boundary, such that $$\Delta\phi = c$$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator.

My intuition is that you can find a closed curve and after reparametrization, equation becomes $$\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial\theta^2}=c$$ on the curve,
which is impossible. But I don't know if this is right or how to write it rigourously.

Comment: @mfl Thanks, you are right! Can you write this as answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Your intuitive argument doesn't seem to make any use of the hypothesis that the manifold is compact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the manifold is compact, if $\Delta \phi=c$ then it is

$$0=\int_M \Delta \phi=\int_M c=c\mathrm{vol}(M).$$ Then, it follows that $c$ must be $0.$

On the other hand, any constant function $\phi$ satisfies $\Delta \phi=0.$

Comment: what about the converse: any function $\Delta \phi=0$ is constant on $M$?